# PHP Uploading files - image only checking

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I have a simple PHP upload script I have started. I am not the best to PHP. Just looking for some suggestions.

I want to limit my script to only .JPG, .JPEG, .GIF and .PNG

Is this possible?

```
<?php
/*
    Temp Uploader
*/

    # vars
    $mx=rand();
    $advid=$_REQUEST["advid"];
    $hash=md5(rand);

    # create our temp dir
    mkdir("./uploads/tempads/".$advid."/".$mx."/".$hash."/", 0777, true);

    # upload dir
    $uploaddir = './uploads/tempads/'.$advid.'/'.$mx.'/'.$hash.'/';
    $file = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    // I was thinking of a large IF STATEMENT HERE ..

    # upload the file
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $file)) {
      $result = 1;
    } else {
      $result = 0;
    }

    sleep(10);
    echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: http://cowburn.info/2008/01/13/get-file-extension-comparison/ - apparently strrchr is the fastest way

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, quite easily. But first off, you need some extra bits:

```
// never assume the upload succeeded
if ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['file']['error']);
}

$info = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
if ($info === FALSE) {
   die("Unable to determine image type of uploaded file");
}

if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
   die("Not a gif/jpeg/png");
}
```

Relevant docs: [file upload errors](http://php.net/manual/features.file-upload.errors.php), [getimagesize](http://php.net/getimagesize) and [image constants](http://php.net/manual/image.constants.php).

Comment: Beat me to it - this method makes sure the file *is* an image, not just *named like* an image.

Comment: The only caveat is that GD is not oob for PHP and can be finicky. finfo_file is standard in PHP after version 5.3.0 and will do a content-based check as well.

Comment: How can I check the file resolution too? IE Size if width and height??

Comment: A gif is a gif. They all share the same magic numbers at the start of the file.

Comment: At the last `if-statement`, shouldn't it be `||` instead of `&&`?

Comment: @Jessica: no. then ANY image type would pass. it's a `!=` comparison.

Comment: "Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead." See http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: The manual says that the file stuffed into `getimagesize` must be a valid image. To check for the content type of a file, use `mime_content_type` instead, see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php

Comment: **This is BAD** and opens up your site to potential remote code execution. Anyone can put exactuable code inside the image header (where the metadata is stored and text is considered valid) and `getimagesize` will still think it is an image, thus accepting the file and potentially allowing PHP code to be executed server side. Use [mime_content_type](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php) instead.

Answer (score 6):

File path isn't necessarily the best way to check if an image really is an image. I could take a malicious javascript file, rename it to have the .jpg extension, and upload it. Now when you try to display it in your website, I may have just compromised your site.

Here is a function to validate it really is an image:

```
<?php
  function isImage($img){
      return (bool)getimagesize($img);
  }
?>
```

Comment: `Do not use getimagesize() to check that a given file is a valid image. Use a purpose-built solution such as the Fileinfo extension instead.` - [Docs](http://php.net/getimagesize)

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
<?php

function isimage(){
$type=$_FILES['my-image']['type'];     

$extensions=array('image/jpg','image/jpe','image/jpeg','image/jfif','image/png','image/bmp','image/dib','image/gif');
    if(in_array($type, $extensions)){
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

    if(isimage()){
        //do codes..
    }

?>
```

Comment: Your post was flagged as low quality because it was all code.  Try explaining what you did.

Comment: This was my easiest and worked

Answer (score -1):

Or take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Answer (score -3):

```
if (substr($_FILES["fieldName"]["name"], strlen($_FILES["fieldName"]["name"])-4) == ".jpg")
{
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fieldName"]["tmp_name"],$path."/".$_FILES['fieldName']['name']))
    {
        echo "image sucessfully uploaded!";
    }
}
```

similarly you can check for other image formats too.

Comment: You're assuming the remote user is not malicious and won't just rename `nastyvirus.exe` to `cutekittens.jpg`.