# Url button from web

Tags: html

There are buttons like this:

```
 <p>
   Upload:<br>
  <br>
   <input type="file" name="datafile" size="40">
  </p>
```

Is it possible to have a button in which user can include (copy/paste) the url of a photo somewhere in the web?

Example: I want to have press button which will ask the user to insert a link of image from web like [this](http://ih3.redbubble.net/image.12233164.0548/fc,550x550,white.jpg) and it will take the picture

Comment: What are you trying to do with this

Comment: What are you using server side to process this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what that means. Please elaborate.

Comment: by button, do you mean input field?

Comment: @Roi513 you mean to say that you want users to upload only images, right? If yes, this may interest you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314164/php-uploading-files-image-only-checking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that this is a vague answer, but it's only as vague as your question.  If this is NOT what you want, please tell us what the end result should look like.

```js
function writeImage(url){
  
  document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="' + url + '"/>';
  
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="imgUrl" size="30" value="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" placeholder="image url here"/><input type="button" value="Insert Image" onclick="writeImage(document.getElementById('imgUrl').value)"/>
```

Copy and paste this into a webpage:

```
    <input type="text" id="imgUrl" size="30" value="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" placeholder="image url here"/><input type="button" value="Insert Image" onclick="writeImage(document.getElementById('imgUrl').value)"/>

<script>
function writeImage(url){

  var URL = url;

  var myWindow = window.open("", "_blank", "width=300, height=200");

myWindow.document.write("<img src='" + url + "'/>");

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Check my new code.  Paste it into a webpage.  Please upvote my answer if you think it works well.

Comment: You might want to preload the image. In this example the image loads quickly but in some cases the image may take time to load and you might want to preload it with javascript. Ie. load the image then insert the html.