# Retrieve an image from a window

Tags: php

Here there is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27278081/4293251) for an image from a url.

I try to retrieve it from a submit process using this but it it not the right echo.

```
 <?php echo $_POST['onclick']; ?>
```

Comment: Please explain further, what are you storing, an image url? And how are you submitting it? And what should it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job for you, please look into php's $_POST more because this question is unneeded and can easily be searched for on the internet.

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST['image'])) {
        echo "<img src='" . $_POST['image'] . "' />";
    }

?>

<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="image" />
    <button type="submit">Show image</button>
</form>
```