# Allow certain image formats not working

Tags: php, getimagesize

I'm trying to allow certain formats get uploaded to my website. I'm using the call `getimagesize()` to identify the image type (which is returned as the third parameter). I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314268/4861207) to perform that. Here's the code:

```
$img=$_FILES['img'];
$info = getimagesize($img);

if (($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_GIF) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_JPEG) && ($info[2] !== IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
    echo json_encode(array('bad' => 'Bad Format'));
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('good' => 'Good format'));
    exit();
}
```

No matter what file format I try uploading, I always get the `else` statement. `echo json_encode(array('good' => 'Good format'));`

Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You're comparing against `const`'s - `IMAGETYPE_JPEG`, put them in quotes to compare as a string - `'IMAGETYPE_JPEG'`. Also, you're using `&&` (and), you want to be using `||` (or).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it will always be false since you are using the `&&` operator.

```
$img=$_FILES['img'];
$accepted = array('image/jpeg','image/png','image/gif');

if (in_array($img['type'],$accepted)) {
    echo json_encode(array('bad' => 'Good Format'));
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('good' => 'Bad format'));
    exit();
}
```

use the `||` or `or` to get what you want.

Doing it with `getimagesize()`

```
$img=$_FILES['img'];
$info = getimagesize($img['tmp_name']); //pass the file
```

Change your condition to `||` (or)

```
if (($info[2] === IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) || ($info[2] === IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
    echo json_encode(array('bad' => 'Good Format'));
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('good' => 'Bad format'));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but now I get the first if statement all the time

Comment: you are using the `getimagesize()` differently.  you must pass the `$_FILES['img'][tmp_name]` for it to work eg: `getimagesize($_FILES['img'][tmp_name])`.  since the file type is already given on `$_FILES`.  no need to use `getimagesize()`.

Comment: Can please you show me how to do it with `getimagesize()`

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong operator. You're using `&&` (and), which means **ALL** 3 if conditions **have to be met** for it to return what you want. Also, you're comparing against a `const`, which I assume is where you want to compare against a string. So you could easily clean up your code, like this:

```
if( !in_array($info[2], array('IMAGETYPE_GIF', 'IMAGETYPE_JPEG','IMAGETYPE_PNG') ) ) {
    echo json_encode(array('bad' => 'Good Format'));
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('good' => 'Bad format'));
    exit();
}
```

Or actually use the `||` (or) operator to run against your conditions:

```
if (($info[2] === IMAGETYPE_GIF) || ($info[2] === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) || ($info[2] === IMAGETYPE_PNG)) {
    echo json_encode(array('bad' => 'Good Format'));
    exit();
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('good' => 'Bad format'));
    exit();
}
```

Comment: I tried both examples, and I now get the first if statement.

Comment: I get the first if statement with whatever file I upload

Comment: Can you `print_r($info)` and show me what's returned?

Comment: Where can I see the results?