# Wordpress Contact Form 7 check file server side

Tags: wordpress, file, attachment, contact-form-7

Here is my problem:

In a form made by Contact Form 7 I allow the download of a pdf, jpg, or jpeg file type. 
My concern is that the extension control is not fully performed.

Indeed, if I take a "test.exe" file and rename it "text.jpg", I can submit my form and there's no errors...

Is there a solution to test this? (e.g. by the mime test)

And if so where should I implement code?

Thank you in advance for your answers and sorry for my English (I am French...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who have the same question, here my solution :

In `wp-includes/functions.php` :

```
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_file*', 'cf7_custom_file_validation', 10, 2);
add_filter('wpcf7_validate_file', 'cf7_custom_file_validation', 10, 2);

function cf7_custom_file_validation ($result, $tag) {
    if ($tag->name === 'file-586') {
        $contentType = mime_content_type($_FILES[$tag->name]['tmp_name']);

        if ($contentType !== 'image/png' && $contentType !== 'image/jpeg' && $contentType !== 'application/pdf') {
            $result->invalidate($tag, 'Ce type de fichier n\'est pas supporté');
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found for you some usefull answers in our forum:
[PHP Uploading files - image only checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314164/php-uploading-files-image-only-checking)

Try this answer:

```
<?php
  function isImage($img){
      return (bool)getimagesize($img);
  }
?>
```

Posted by Jeremy Harris.

Here is manual of getimagesize()
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.getimagesize.php

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In full php, I have no problem doing it. My problem is to integrate it in Wordpress (I'm new to wordpress) and I don't want to break the Contact From plugin (for later updates).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress uses the filter `upload_mimes` to control what MIME types are allowed site-wide.  You can customize this list by adding the following to wp-includes/functions.php:

```
function safe_mime_types($mime_types){
    unset($mime_types['exe']);  //remove .exe support
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'safe_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

You can also add acceptable MIME types:

```
function safe_mime_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';  //add .svg support
    unset($mime_types['exe']);
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'safe_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to do this in entire web site. Only in a particular page (made with Contact Form 7).